# Basic menu program in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to make a simple C program, which prints out a menu of options and when the option is chosen and the task is completed, the user is being redirected back to the main menu. I keep getting the error "dash: 2: 1: not found". Each option is a separate function and is chosen by a switch statement. I tried adding a while loop, declaring the function in different ways, but I keep getting this same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int power(int a, int n){
    int s = 1;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n != 0) {
        s *= a;
        --n;
}
return ("Answer = %d", s);

}

int main()
{
int a, n, op;
printf("\n\n\nMenu: \n");
printf("Option 1: a**n\n");
printf("Option 2: Is a in n?\n");
printf("Option 3: How many times is a written in n?\n");
printf("Option 4: Is n a prime number?\n");
printf("Option 5: nth number of Fibonacci sequence\n");
printf("Option 6: Max a in Fibonacci sequence that is less than n\n");
printf("Option 7: Min a in Fibonacci sequence that is greater than n\n");
switch(op){
    case 1: power(a,n); break;
}
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this return... you should return an int... maybe you wanted to call printf instead of return? Also... you are not reading any input from the user, variable op contains a random value

Comment: *dash: 2: 1: not found*... Um... are you feeding a C program to a shell, instead of compiling it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding the necessary user input did the job. I'm just new to the concept of functions and don't understand everything yet.

Comment: This isn't the question you're asking, but this isn't going to work like you want because a and n are being passed by value.  So &a (and &n) within power() will refer to the address of the copy of a (and n) stored locally on power()'s stack frame, not what main() can see.  You should rewrite power() to take pointers as its arguments, and then pass it pointers to a and n in main (and adjust your scanf() calls accordingly--since the a and n in power() are already pointers, you can pass them directly to scanf() without needing to take their address--which would give you a pointer to the pointer).